# Erlang memory fragmentation

Tags: memory, garbage-collection, erlang, memory-fragmentation

Our Erlang server looks have a serious memory leak, the VM memory usage is low but top is high.

## Env

`Erlang: R16B02 
OS: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS \n \l   X86_64`

## Erlang VM

```erlang
> erlang:memory().
[{total,424544992},
 {processes,293961840},
 {processes_used,293937232},
 {system,130583152},
 {atom,553569},
 {atom_used,521929},
 {binary,9794704},
 {code,14041920},
 {ets,5632280}]
```

## Allocated Memory

```erlang
> recon_alloc:memory(allocated).
2570059776

 recon_alloc:memory(allocated_types).
[{binary_alloc,163577856},
 {driver_alloc,11010048},
 {eheap_alloc,2165309440},
 {ets_alloc,11010048},
 {fix_alloc,50855936},
 {ll_alloc,156237824},
 {sl_alloc,2097152},
 {std_alloc,6815744},
 {temp_alloc,3145728}]
```

## allocate binary

```erlang
> recon:bin_leak(5).
[{<0.440.0>,-769,
  [{current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}},
   {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}]},
 {<0.446.0>,-230,
  [{current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}},
   {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}]},
 {<0.450.0>,-179,
  [{current_function,{gen_server,loop,6}},
   {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}]},
 {<0.12497.0>,-147,
  [{current_function,{gen,do_call,4}},
   {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}]},
 {<0.434.0>,-145,
  [{current_function,{cberl_worker,mget,4}},
   {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}]}]
```

## Do garbage

```erlang
7> erlang:garbage_collect().
true
8> erlang:memory().
[{total,381782256},
 {processes,251371752},
 {processes_used,251361352},
 {system,130410504},
 {atom,553569},
 {atom_used,521929},
 {binary,9230384},
 {code,14041920},
 {ets,5675528}]
> recon_alloc:memory(allocated_types).
[{binary_alloc,150994944},
 {driver_alloc,11010048},
 {eheap_alloc,2154823680},
 {ets_alloc,11010048},
 {fix_alloc,50855936},
 {ll_alloc,156237824},
 {sl_alloc,2097152},
 {std_alloc,6815744},
 {temp_alloc,3145728}]
```

## Fragmentation

And I check `recon_alloc:fragmentation(current)` and `recon_alloc:fragmentation(max)`, find some allocator current usage is lower than max usage.

### Current usage

```erlang
 {{binary_alloc,0},
  [{sbcs_usage,1.0},
   {mbcs_usage,0.037804497612847224},
   {sbcs_block_size,0},
   {sbcs_carriers_size,0},
   {mbcs_block_size,178384},
   {mbcs_carriers_size,4718592}]},
 {{binary_alloc,2},
  [{sbcs_usage,2.0},
   {mbcs_usage,0.05326200786389803},
   {sbcs_block_size,0},
   {sbcs_carriers_size,0},
   {mbcs_block_size,4775112},
   {mbcs_carriers_size,89653248}]},
 {{binary_alloc,1},
  [{sbcs_usage,2.0},
   {mbcs_usage,0.0643930146188447},
   {sbcs_block_size,0},
   {sbcs_carriers_size,0},
   {mbcs_block_size,4456384},
   {mbcs_carriers_size,69206016}]},
```

### Max usage

```erlang
 {{binary_alloc,0},
  [{sbcs_usage,1.0},
   {mbcs_usage,0.7732696533203125},
   {sbcs_block_size,0},
   {sbcs_carriers_size,0},
   {mbcs_block_size,24324960},
   {mbcs_carriers_size,31457280}]},
 {{binary_alloc,2},
  [{sbcs_usage,1.0},
   {mbcs_usage,0.938345729714573},
   {sbcs_block_size,0},
   {sbcs_carriers_size,0},
   {mbcs_block_size,149064912},
   {mbcs_carriers_size,158859264}]},
 {{binary_alloc,0},
  [{sbcs_usage,1.0},
   {mbcs_usage,0.7732696533203125},
   {sbcs_block_size,0},
   {sbcs_carriers_size,0},
   {mbcs_block_size,24324960},
   {mbcs_carriers_size,31457280}]},
```

Does is mean Erlang server have lots of Memory fragmentation and How can I move on?

Comment: They are different issue

Comment: I recommend you [put this on the ML](http://www.erlang.org/static/doc/mailinglist.html) rather than here. Figuring this out will likely require a discussion, not a one-shot answer. That will infuriate the powers that be. The Erlang community on SO is pretty tiny, also, and I don't know much about Riak (and I'm not sure if the other two guys around here deal with it much either).

Comment: Thanks, I will post a thread.

Comment: What do you mean by _but top is high_?

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil  Means process in top eat up most of memory

Comment: @linbo: Is it virtual or real memory? You should not be bothered by virtual memory, there is plenty of it.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil  RES memory， I posted a thread in Erlang maillist, discussed there.

Comment: @linbo: I see. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The memory fragmentation in Erlang is much more complicated than it looks like, and is a deep problem already approached.

Take a look at this post from Fred https://blog.heroku.com/logplex-down-the-rabbit-hole#how-erlang-39-s-memory-stuff-works

It shows the whole problem, the Erlang memory fragmentation is not solved but can be reduced.